# Use AJAX to display multiple partials

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, arrays, escaping

I feel like this should be really simple...

I make an AJAX call, where I send an array of strings (defined in my call-back function in my controller) to a .js.erb file:

In my rails controller:

```
@array = ["render partial a", "render partial b", "render partial c"]

render :action => "show_options"
```

In my show_options.js.erb file, I want to make an escape_javascript call on each each of the strings in @array, e.g.

```
var show_1 = '<%= escape_javascript( @array[0] ) %>'
var show_2 = '<%= escape_javascript( @array[1] ) %>'
var show_3 = '<%= escape_javascript( @array[2] ) %>'
```

The issue is that the number of array elements is variable. 
How would I set up some sort of loop to ensure I can handle any number of array elements?

I was trying something along these lines, but I can't figure out how to insert the index number (i) into the ruby expression.

```
for (i = 0; i < @array_lenth; i++) { 
    var show =+ '<%= escape_javascript( @array[i] ) %>'
}
```

I'm not sure how else to do it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's a `.js.erb` file, you can insert Ruby-style loops:

```
<% @array.each_with_index do |partial, index| %>
    var show_<%= index + 1 %> = '<%= escape_javascript(partial) %>'
<% end %>
```